# Google Cloud DLP API: Default Secure Communication

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

We are using java library *com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dlp* to make Google Cloud DLP calls. On the client side, we are utilizing *DlpServiceClient*. I know for the fact that it internally uses *gRPC*. Wondering whether the default communication uses *SSL/TLS*?

Answer (score 0):

The default communication doesn’t use SSL/TLS.

Token-based authentication with Google: gRPC provides a generic mechanism (described below) to attach metadata based credentials to requests and responses. Additional support for acquiring access tokens (typically OAuth2 tokens) while accessing Google APIs through gRPC is provided for certain auth flows.

For applications running in GCE, a default service account and corresponding OAuth2 scopes can be configured during setup. At run-time, this credential handles communication with the authentication systems to obtain OAuth2 access tokens and attaches them to each outgoing RPC on the corresponding channel.

[gRPC-enabled Cloud APIs generally have both REST and RPC interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/auth), so rather than just using JSON over HTTP to talk to the REST interface, gRPC-enabled API clients can also use protocol buffers and gRPC over HTTP2 to talk to the RPC interface.

Comment: Our application is hosted in GCE and we are using service account. Since _google-cloud-dlp_ library is a wrapper around gRPC. Not quite sure what is happening behind the scenes. We are not making any explicit REST calls. How can I figure out whether there is a secure communication is happening?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply @Hao Z! Really appreciated.

Looks like we are using OAuth2 access token since I found _client_id, auth_uri, token_uri_ in the configuration. Could you please throw some light on communication channel between Java Client and DLP Server while making a DLP call eg: TLS1.2, SSL. I found the following config in the application.

_auth_provider_x509_cert_url_
_client_x509_cert_url_

Comment: I’m not familiar with JAVA,  when you use a service account outside of Google Cloud, you must first establish the identity of the service account. Public/private key pairs provide a secure way of accomplishing this goal. I recommend this document [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) for your question.